# Two child elements in a parent div element

Tags: html, css

As shown below, there are two div elements in a parent element. One of these elements has a width of 100 pixels and the other covers the entire remaining width. I want to make the second div element have a variable width according to the parent div's size, but the first div element remains constant.(css pure pls)

[Two child elements in a widget with constant width and variable width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bvoJ.jpg)

```css
.comments {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: right;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd;
}

.comments-text {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.comments-img {
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

    .comments-img img {
        width: 75px;
        height: 75px;
        float: right;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

.comments-text b,
.comments-text .comments-body {
    float: right;
}

.comments-text b {
    color: #0c80df;
}

.comments-date {
    float: left;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.comments-body {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div class="comments">
        <div class="comments-img">
            <img src="http://xup.ir/images/37358315942326655914.png" />
        </div>

        <div class="comments-text">
            <b>
                username
            </b>
            <br />
            <span class="comments-body">
                text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
            </span>
            <br />
            <span class="comments-date">
                2018.08.06
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please show some code that you tried

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask] and add [mcve] of you code and explain what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: @Esko I added codes

Comment: @Nandita Arora Sharma The codes were added to the question

Comment: Added an answer. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using flex like shown below.

Basically I updated this style

```
.comments {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

And removed all float properties.

```css
.comments {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.comments-text {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.comments-img {
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

    .comments-img img {
        width: 75px;
        height: 75px;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

   
.comments-text b {
    color: #0c80df;
}

.comments-date {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="comments">
        <div class="comments-img">
            <img src="http://xup.ir/images/37358315942326655914.png" />
        </div>

        <div class="comments-text">
            <b>
                username
            </b>
            <br />
            <span class="comments-body">
                text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
            </span>
            <br />
            <span class="comments-date">
                2018.08.06
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm think you need more learn about css calc.

If i'm rigth understand your question, you need to do somes like this:

```css
#parent {
  width: 390px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 80px;
}

#first-child {
  width: 20%;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px 0 5px 2%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#second-child {
  /*  Now we using % for width  */
  width: 74%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  float: left;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 5px 2%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
HTML part

<div id="parent">
  <div id="first-child"></div>
  <div id="second-child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way other than using calc? Because this command is not properly used on some older browsers (IE 8).

Comment: @Hamidreza Yes, you always can use percent to make width flexeble. I'm edit my answer